# How to read XML with special character in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, windows

I have to read a xml which contains special characters like Ã. How to use Encoding while reading xml using xmldocument,since no reader is used.

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(file.FullName);
var q = from p in xml.Descendants("xyz")
        select new abc()
```

Comment: If it is a `Ã` then probably the file is UTF8. Strange that it isn't auto-recognized.

Comment: In streamreader we can use Encoding.UTF8.How to use when reading xml using linq

Comment: Try `using (var sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName, Encoding.UTF8)) { var xml = XDocument.Load(sr); var q = ...  }`

Comment: As far as UTF-8 is concerned, Ã doesn't have anything special. Does your file have an encoding attribute in the XML header?

Comment: @xanatos Thank you! It Worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the `XDocument.Load` isn't using the right encoding. From your example (`Ã`) it seems the file is UTF8. You could try forcing the encoding:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(file.FullName, Encoding.UTF8)) 
{ 
    var xml = XDocument.Load(sr); 
    var q = ... 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the encoding to "ISO-8859-1" or "ISO-8959-15" in the XML document.
Both encondings provide complete coverage for Spanish/Catalan languages.

Comment: The question was not about modifying source document.